Tap to click setting ignored after upgrade from 18 to 22
I just updated from ubuntu 18 to ubuntu 22 and tap to click is stuck on, even if I turn it off in settings.  I had it turned off in ubuntu 18, and the settings still said it was off in ubuntu 22, but tapping causes a click.  Turning the setting on and off does nothing, taps always produce clicks regardless of the setting.  Additionally, the natural scrolling setting does nothing, its always the same direction regardless of the setting.
This upgrade was done in 2 steps, first upgrading from 18 to 20, then 20 to 22.  I did not interact with my computer while it was running version 20 except to upgrade to version 22.  I did not think to write down the exact version numbers, if someone can tell me how to find out what version I was running before the update I can share.
I also tried
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false

and true, it also did nothing

Was this a re-install? as the Ubuntu Release Upgrader tool won't upgrade a 18.04 system to 22.04 directly..   Release upgrades will keep most of your old settings, where as a new install will give you a fresh system with your system having the newer defaults (not what prior releases had as defaults).  Your details are unclear (18 & 18.04 are different systems too, 18 being the snap only version of 18.04).

I upgraded to 20, then immediately to 22.  I have no idea what the settings in 20 were.  I also don't know the exact version of 18 and 20 I was running, since I've updated from them and didn't think to write it down.
